# basestream.seek displays?

Tags: c#

I have a text file called message.txt which has "abcdef' as text in it.

Now, code below outputs:

**a** if I seek with offset 0

**?** if I seek with offset  1 or 2

**a** (again) if I seek with offset  3

**b** if I seek with offset  4

**c** if I seek with offset  5
and so on.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Message.txt");
        sr.BaseStream.Seek(2, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        Console.WriteLine((char)sr.Read());
    }
```

QUESTION

From offset 3 it behaves as expected. But ideally the same should have been the output starting with offset 1. Hence,

Q1. Why same output **a** happens with offset 0 and 3?

Q2. Why I get a ? for offset 1 and 2

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have BOM at the start of your file. Byte order mark, the unicode header.

Watch your file in some hex editor. (Rename to .bin and open in Visual Studio.) This particular BOM tells the computer that this is a UTF-8 file.

Comment: but why seek with offset 0 gives a?

Comment: eD: This is due to how StreamReader/TextReader works. Seek method operates on binary bytes, while StreamReader/TextReader operates in text mode. Position 0 is start of file and there's 'a' letter. It has to read 4 bytes from file to read first letter. (This is true as long as you use u.s. latin alphabet.) If you skip 3 bytes, it reads 'a' as well, because there's is 'a' on that position. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are three likely factors here:

- encoding: in most encodings, bytes != characters
- buffers: if you `Seek` a base stream, you **must** tell the reader to drop any buffers it may have, or it will get badly confused; to do this call `sr.DiscardBufferedData()`
- byte order marks at the start of the file